# Updating a Rails model via Restangular (ie JSON)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I need someone who knows a lot of Rails, AngularJS and Restangular, I'm tryng to update a model from Rails via AngularJS, but I am having a complication with the parameters that are being sent...

I'm using this function from an AngularJS controller to first capture the data I have in a form (data which is assigned to `poll_updated` variable), and then send the update request to Rails...

```
  $scope.editPoll = function() {   
    var poll_updated = {title: $scope.title, description: $scope.description, allow_anonymous_answer: $scope.allow_anonymous_answer, initial_message: $scope.initial_message, final_message: $scope.final_message};

    console.log(poll_updated);

    Restangular.one('polls', poll.id).put(poll_updated).then(function(poll_updated) {
      $state.go('add_data_poll', poll_updated);
    });
  };
```

Note that `poll.id` is the id of the poll that will be modified and that I print `poll_updated` (supposedly the new data) trough the console.

This is what I get in Google Chrome's console...

[image: Google Chrome's console]

Which is absolutely correct, those are the params that I sent...

Now I show you the Rails's log

[image: Rails console]

In the first rectange we can still see that the parameters sent are still correct (and I can say that the id is also correct), **but the problem is in the second rectangle... here I show the parameters `poll_params` which is used to update the model, AND IT ONL CONTAINS THE ID...**

Here's the code of the update action in the polls_controller from Rails...

```
def update
  puts "<(PARAMETERS)>: " + poll_params.to_s
  respond_to do |format|
    if @poll.update(poll_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @poll, notice: 'Poll was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @poll }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @poll.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I've done several tests and the only conclusion I reached is that the only problem is that `poll_params` don't get all the parameters that I sent, just the `id`.

How can I solve this problem?

These are the parameters I allow to be updated...

```
def poll_params
  params.require(:poll).permit(:user, :title, :description, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message)
end
```

So what could've the problem?

Comment: basically, did you see the `poll: { id: '..')`, you have nothing inside the `poll` root key and you need to wrap all the data there.. Have a look at how to wrap this by reading http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html . Let me know if you still stuck there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the correct behavior. Your `params` hash looks like this:

```
{
  "allow_anonymous_answer" => false,
  "description" => "AAA",
  "final_message" => "AAA",
  "initial_message" => "AAA",
  "title" => "Poll B",
  "poll" => {
    "id" => 137
  }
}
```

But the `poll_params` hash includes only one pair because you only extract the value of the `poll` from the `params` hash.

```
{
  "id" => 137
}
```

`require` returns only the value with the specified key(`:poll`).
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

So, your `poll_params` method should look like this:

```
def poll_params
  params.permit(:user, :title, :description, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message).except(:poll)
end
```

The alternative solution would be to configure `Restangular` to send all attributes nested into the `poll` parameter.